# How to get Authentication Type (like WindowsIdentity.AuthenticationType property)

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, visual-c++

In C#, the following code would give authentication type of current user:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AuthenticationType;
```

The returned value would be either **NTLM** or **Kerberos**.

How do I get same information using Windows API. I tried locating information through `GetTokenInformation`, but none of information classes serve the information. I couldn't find any functions in LSA or Authorization also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use LsaGetLogonSessionData().  The returned SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA.AuthenticationPackage contains the authentication package name.  Get the LUID you need from GetTokenInformation

Comment: I guess it would work, I would give it a try. But it requires Admin rights.